# ISoftware required for simulation of Vehicle Collision in map

Tags: windows, simulation, openstreetmap, iot

I am looking for the software to simulate the scenario which is given below. Scenario is related with VANET Internet of Vehicles. Please read scenario and give your suggestion.

a.) In Open Street Map in which it will have a moving vehicles.

b.) When vehicles collide with each other, i have to transmit that collision information to other vehicles in a network making a Vehicular ad-hoc Network.

c.) Transmitted information to other vehicles includes coordinates of accidental location.

So, please help me that how can i simulate the above described scenario.

Note: I want simulator for Windows 64 Bit.

Comment: Should the simulation take immediate connectivity between all vehicles as granted? If not, describe what problems should be taken into account by the model (example: network latency, antenna destruction, etc)

Comment: All vehicles are interconnected, so that they can share information between each other.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of protocol(s) are you using? If RPL is an option, then you can quickly start with Contiki OS, which has a simulator (Cooja) to run your experiment. NS2 (for Linux) is a much more open and general simulator with very big capabilities.

Comment: I am using windows 64 bit platform, so please suggest any simulator which can simulate my above scenario.

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi: You should have detailed that OS requirement in your question. Please add ALL requirements now, for instance budget etc.

Comment: I suggest you consider the simulator that fits your needs. If it doesn't run to your win64, then you should consider a virtual machine. Usually, those simulators run in Linux.

Comment: Ok then please suggest me some simulator that suits my above scenario keeping OS on side.

Comment: NS2, NS3, contiki-cooja.